# Shiny app - can't read my file (linux)

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, shiny

I am really in trouble with my shiny app.

I've installed a shiny server on a linux vm, but everytime I try to run it, it fails (it works locally).

I suspect a problem to read the file.

My three files (obs.csv, ui.R, server.R) are stored in /srv/shiny-server/app_test

I have changed the authorizations of obs.csv

```
sudo chmod g+w app_anfr/obs.csv
```

Here the way I call the file in ui.R and server.R

```
obs=fread("obs.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,encoding="UTF-8")
```

Any idea?

Comment: Try to look in `/var/log/shiny-server/*.log` to see what's causing it to crash then work from there.

Comment: The `sudo chmod` line looks like it's changing a file in a folder called `app_anfr`. Does Shiny know how to find this?

Comment: Yes, it only replace the name of the file by test for this post.

Comment: finally solved the problem changing permissions to a+x,a+r,a+w